# What mean that Itô integral is not pathwise defined?

Tags: probability

Let $(X_t)$ a stochastic process and denote $I(t)=\int_0^t X_sdB_s$. In a book I'm reading it's written : Not that we cannot say that at $\omega $, the integral depend only on the path $t\mapsto B_t(\omega )$ and $t\mapsto X_t(\omega )$ since the integral is not pathwise defined.

What mean "the integral is not pathwise defined" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For almost all  $\omega$ the function $s \to B_s(\omega)$ is of unbounded variation so we cannot consider the integral as an ordinary [Riemann Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral).

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't see what mean "it's not pathwise defined".

Comment: Saying  that it is pathwise defined means you can fix $\omega$ and define  the integral using just Calculus and no Probability Theory. Such a thing is not possible for Brownian Motion.  Also the rules of Calculus are not  available for Ito integrals.  @Walace